# Xamarin Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, io

I am trying to save a bitmap to the Android storage.
My code looks like this:

```
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "Pictures/profile_picture.png");
var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
stream.Close();
```

But the application enters break mode and it says:

**System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path.**

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance, Zoedingl.

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, it does.

Comment: What is the value of `filePath` ?

Comment: @SushiHangover the value of filePath is Android/data/com.oedingsoftware.retrogamez/files/Pictures/profile_picture.png

Comment: When i created the folder `Picture`(if the folder exists, ignore to create the folder), there is no error with your code. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/3GAZDZH

Comment: @Wendy Zang I am even more confused right now. I create the folder in another part of the code. SO maybe I should move that towards  the place as you did?

Comment: You could try what i did. If you still have issue for this, could you provide a code sample on github for us to test?

Answer (score 1):

"Pictures" directory is not created. So, you are getting "Could not find a part of the path" error. Change code as below or you can create directory for "Pictures" then use same code should work.

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "profile_picture.png");
```

Code for creating directory

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "Pictures"));
```

Comment: The folder exists already, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zoedingl What was the issue then? if folder already exists then, "could not find path" issue should not come. Could you please tell what was the issue. This may help others who come across this kind of issue.

Comment: I got exactly that error code and idk why